# java thread synchronization - this shouldn't be working, but it is :) -

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am following examples from [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html)

I've modified the `processCommand` as-

```
private void processCommand() throws InterruptedException {
        this.command = "xyz";
}
```

Full code-

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s) {
        this.command = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Commad at start :" + command);
        try {
            processCommand();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Command after processCommand : " + command);


    }

    private void processCommand() throws InterruptedException {
        this.command = "xyz";

    }
}
```

Now, I expect to see synchronization issue, right? Basically, when

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+' Start. Command = '+command);
```

is executed, it **CAN** pick-up the value `xyz`, right? but I never see it. I've experimented with various values in Thread.Sleep.

So what makes `this.command = "xyz";` statement threadsafe in this case?

I am starting thread in this way -

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
```

Comment: Show us your full code.

Comment: What makes you think this is thread safe? Your code has no synchronization on the `command` variable, and it has no guarantees about the value of `command` if it was being accessed by multiple threads.  Just because your code isn't throwing an error, doesn't mean its right or safe :)

Comment: @greedybuddha - exactly- I don't think it is threadsafe but my experiments are showing it is. How do I induce race condition in this example?

Comment: @user375868 Start multiple threads , and try to modify `command`.

Comment: @tarrsalah I am already doing that.

Comment: System.out.println is synchronized so it is unlikely that you could see anything unexpected here...

Comment: "Why doesn't my buggy code do what I expect?" Fix the bugs and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UPDATE***

It is still not entirely what the complete program looks like ... but based on what I think it is, I cannot see any point where it is not thread-safe.

There are two points where `command` is assigned and two points where the value is read.

1. The main thread assigns `command` in the constructor.
2. A second thread reads `command` in `run()` before calling `processCommand`.
3. The second thread assigns `command` in `processCommand`
4. The second thread reads `command` in `run()` after calling `processCommand`.

The last three events occur on the same thread, so no synchronization is required.  The first and second events occur on different threads, but there *should* be a "happens before" relation between the main thread and worker thread at that point.

- If the main thread were to `start()` the second thread, that would provide the happens before.  (The JLS says so.)
- But actually we are using `ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Runnable)` to do the hand-over, and according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for `Executor`:

  > Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

In summary, all 4 events of interest are properly synchronized, and there are no race conditions involving `command`.

---

However, even if this was not thread-safe you would have difficulty *demonstrating* that non-thread-safe behaviour.

- The main reason you cannot demonstrate it is that the actual non-safeness is due to Java memory model.  Changes to the `command` variable only need to be flushed to main memory if there is synchronization point or something to establish the "happens before".  But they can be flushed anyway ... and they usually are ... especially if there is a long enough time gap, or a system call that causes a context switch.  In this case you have both.
- A second reason is that the `System.err` and `System.out` objects are internally synchronized, and if you are not careful with the way you call them you can eliminate the thread-safety problem you trying to demonstrate.

---

This is "the thing" about thread-safety issues involving non-synchronised access to shared variables.  The actual race conditions often involve very small time windows; i.e. two events that *need* to happen within a few clock cycles (certainly less than a microsecond) for the race to be noticed.  This is likely to happen *rarely*, which is why problems involving race conditions are typically so hard to reproduce.

Comment: +1 because this gives the OP a better idea of how to properly demonstrate a visibility error between the Main thread and an individual Worker thread. However, it should be noted that the original question does show how processCommand is being called.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you don't see a race condition here is

```
Runnable worker = new WorkerThread('' + i);
```

A race condition involves a shared resource. All your worker threads on the other hand are changing their own private member `command`. To induce a race condition you would need to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Runnable worker = new WorkerThread('' + 0);    
  executor.execute(worker);
  worker.setCommand('' + i);
}
```

Now when the worker tries to access the `command` field it could get the stale `0` value or the `i` value.

Comment: @assylias Yes, even static would induce a race condition. It's so simple to make a multi-threaded code trip over! :)

Comment: Nah, `static` doesn't help because there is no discernable correct value for the field. Using `static` would only serve to show that, visibility issues aside, thread interleaving occurs between the main thread and the workers.

Comment: @TimBender The code was fine. OP was actually testing with a sample posted [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html) but with process command replaced as posted in his question. Probably, that's why it was hard to get how it was inducing the race condition for you.

Comment: In order to state that there is a concurrency error, you would need some way to reason about what the value of the field should be. In the example code you posted, it was not possible to do that since you were modifying the same state in a tight loop while queueing other threads to execute a sleep for one second. Now you could rationalize that the value should always be `9` since the loop is likely to complete before the CPU swaps in another thread. However, there is no guarantee. A reasonable outcome might be that the CPU only run iteration 0-4 before the end of the time slice.

Comment: So what I am saying, is that you've not taken into account thread interleaving that could possibly occur as part of the CPUs scheduling mechanism and that is quite alright because it can be hard to understand sometimes that a particular sequence of instructions is not guaranteed to occur in a single time slice even though they are reasonably simple.

Comment: @TimBender If you look at OP's code, he was creating a new runnable for every thread with each thread modifying the state of its own runnable (the command field). OP's question was, "why when some of the threads have already set command to "xyz" (via modified processCommand(); so, I wasn't queuing other threads to execute a sleep now) he still sees the value "i" that was used to initialize the Runnable?" overlooking the fact that they were different Runnables. Hence, I moved the instantiation of the Runnable outside the loop so that every worker thread modifies the same instance of Runnable.

Comment: @TimBender Now, the same thread interleaving would have made its presence felt by some of the threads printing their "i"s properly while others "xyz". I was aware of it and I did notice the same on the console output of the original code where the main thread got swapped out probably after five iterations of the loop. But, I agree I could have made it more clear that I am not expecting the loop to print all "9"s but interleaved values of some "i"s and "xyz".